# App becomes unresponsive when I tried to share my app url from react native iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, react-native-ios, sharing

I am trying to share a link from my react-native iOS app. But when I click the button to share, my app becomes unresponsive.

I am tried using both the code mentioned below, but nothing worked -

```
Share.share({
        message:
          this.props.app_urls.share + "\n" + this.props.app_urls.link_download
      });
```

or

```
Share.share({
        message:
          this.props.app_urls.share,
        url : this.props.app_urls.link_download
      });
```

The same code works fine in android but its not working for iOS. 
What can I do to make it working?

Comment: can you please any error log

Comment: No error log exist in Xcode...app just stops working. And I need to kill the app for running it again

Comment: try using react-native-share, I have used it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share), I have used it without any issues.

**You can use it like this [COPIED]**

> import Share from 'react-native-share';
>
> const shareOptions = {
>       title: 'Share via',
>       url: 'some share url',
>       social: Share.Social.WHATSAPP }; Share.shareSingle(shareOptions);

**Update:**

The issue is still open on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10471), try using timeout, this will resolve the issue for now.

Comment: Thanks for your solution...but it didn't work for me. I am still facing the same issue. As soon as I click on the share button, my app got unresponsive and no error shown in Xcode & terminal.

Comment: Its bit hard to visualize your issue can you provide more detail.

Comment: I got the reason behind this issue...actually my share button exist in a modal. In iOS, it has some conflict when trying to open sharing popup from a modal. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10471

Comment: The issue is still open on github, try using timeout, this will resolve the issue for now.

Comment: I actually changed my popup into a normal screen and it started working. Thanks for your response.